eBPF in real-time systems
I've a question about real-time systems, in particular in LynxOS (LynxOS-178).
I would need information on the compatibility and presence of eBPF in these systems.
Can anyone help me?
I haven't found any documentation online, but I would like to have this information to be able to evaluate which product is best to use to achieve my purpose.

eBPF says it requires a Linux kernel to work, LynxOS does not appear to use a Linux kernel.

eBPF is a kernel feature that only Linux and Windows have.
LynxOS is neither Linux (it claims to have a Linux userspace API, but that doesn't mean it's Linux) nor Windows, and hence:
Neither present not in any way "compatible".
I'll say that it seems pretty questionable that you would do something like eBPF on an operating system that fulfills hard real-time constraints – the things you do with eBPF could be done by a normal task on these, as typically, network handling is just that on an RTOS. And: eBPF especially allows kernel mode code to take arbitrarily long – that's in direct conflict with hard real-time constraints.
So, I'm really a bit surprised to see the requirement "can run eBPF" and "needs to be hard real-time" be combined.

I fully agree. Only to add that, with regards to the authentic Linux kernel, real-time (extensions / patches) do nothing but adding possible preemption points in kernel routines. To this respect, Irrespective of the too true question "what for ?" There is no reason for eBPF not to be compatible with a Linux full-realtimized kernel.

Just… incoherent… at the very least… :-)

well said! It might very well be Serena is something extremely interesting; for example, I could imagine the desire for eBPF arises from the need for low-latency reaction to an emergency packet or something; that would fit the critical control systems use case of Lynx; the question really is how such a Linux-specific solution to Linux-specific problems fit the "larger picture".

First of all, thank you all for your helpful and clear answers.
Do the same considerations are valid for another rtos, VxWorks?
In this case, according to the official documentation, BPF is supported but there aren't any mentions about eBPF instead.

@SerenaSchenone eBPF is really a Linux invention, and you'll find on practically nothing else; BPF exists in multiple UNIX-oid systems. But unlike eBPF, which can be used as code snippet in many calling paths in the Linux kernel, BPF only applies to network packet filtering. Again, if you could tell us what you want to achieve rather than just punctually ask about the existence of something, we could possibly write much more informative answers :)
